# Bitcoin sent but not received.

Tags: sending

This is the log
0 confirmed/ in memory pool
1NJBNxv5c7oB6risrN7Zrh4J5bomjrsrNM
Debit: -0.56748446 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00098910 BTC
Net amount: -0.56847356 BTC
Transaction ID: bc28bfac6984ddeaab814cc73a71fd9f8fb49780997beb39d0f9a8bce519f242
Transaction total size: 98570

Any ideas on what is keeping it from arriving.
I have sent to this address before with no problems.

Thank you

Frank

Comment: This thread might help you... https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it

Comment: In did not set the fee.  In fact I noticed it was smaller than others I sent and was not sure why.  I would gladly pay more, how do I fix this?  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This transaction hasn't confirmed yet because it has a low satoshi/weight unit transactoin fee (0.251 sat/wu, or 1.003 sat/byte).

The transaction you linked is very large, you can check all the inputs using [this link](https://blockchain.info/tx/bc28bfac6984ddeaab814cc73a71fd9f8fb49780997beb39d0f9a8bce519f242?show_adv=true). Transaction fees are calculated according to the amount of data transmitted (tx weight/size), not the amount being transacted, or the receiving address.

[The mempool appears to be fairly empty right now](https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#4d), but with a fee this low, I'm still not sure your tx will confirm anytime soon.

Comment: This transaction tries to gather a massive number of microscopic outputs. That's *very* expensive and such a low fee just won't do it. Whatever is sending you all these tiny payments, figure out some way to get it to stop because you are wasting money.

Comment: I am fairly new to this, mined a Bitcoin and was just sending to a couple of other wallets than Bitcoin core.

Comment: What mining pool / software are you using? You could perhaps set your withdrawal limit higher, so that you end up with less txs of higher value.

Comment: If it does not get any confirmations, will it come back to my wallet so I can fix the fee?